# not able to wget a file from link

Tags: wget, curl

I am trying to use my terminal to download the xls file from this link 
https://www.tase.co.il/_layouts/Tase/ManagementPages/ExcelExport.aspx?sn=none&action=1&SubAction=0&GridId=33&CurGuid={26F9CCE6-D184-43C6-BAB9-CF7848987BFF}&ExportType=1

I made sure the link is good by open the link with chrome and the "download xls file" window shows up

I tried 
wget --no-check-certificate https://www.tase.co.il/_layouts/Tase/ManagementPages/ExcelExport.aspx?sn=none&action=1&SubAction=0&GridId=33&CurGuid={26F9CCE6-D184-43C6-BAB9-CF7848987BFF}&ExportType=1

but without any success

the end point is to create cronjob that will download that latest file from this link and put it in a folder /home/vm1/"dropfilehere"
when the xls file name - has the date and time of download

Comment: Have you tried quoting the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL contains several characters that `bash` considers as "special": `?`, `&`, '{' and '}'. You may either make these characters non-special with the `\` prefix:

```
https://www.tase.co.il/_layouts/Tase/ManagementPages/ExcelExport.aspx\?sn=none\&action=1\&SubAction=0\&GridId=33\&CurGuid=\{26F9CCE6-D184-43C6-BAB9-CF7848987BFF\}\&ExportType=1
```

or, place the whole URL inside `''` quotes to disable shell interpretation:

```
'https://www.tase.co.il/_layouts/Tase/ManagementPages/ExcelExport.aspx?sn=none&action=1&SubAction=0&GridId=33&CurGuid={26F9CCE6-D184-43C6-BAB9-CF7848987BFF}&ExportType=1'
```